# How to scan a a QR code that is on your screen?

Tags: scanning

Does anyone know how to scan a QR code that is on your screen? I am reading a online book with a QR codes and it is to much of a hassle to take another device to scan the codes.

Comment: You can do it with a script, eg. an AppleScript that could form part of an Automator Quick Action.

Comment: Some other suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210470/411282) but I liked the online reader in @sfxedit's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without another device:

- Take a screen shot of your screen and make sure the QR code is captured properly. Crop to the QR code in the screenshot and save the image file using Preview.
- Open this image file in an app like [Barcode Scanner and QR Code Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/leadtools-barcode/id602159087?mt=8). (Alternatively, you can upload the QR image file to an [online QR code reader](https://webqr.com/)).
- The app will decode the QR and provide you the data.